# Shared connection to {HOSTNAME} closed

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm connecting to a remote server by ssh.

While using multiple sessions, it seems to lose connections when my macbook turns into a screensaver mode.

After logging in from the screensaver mode, the sessions are all lost with a message:

> Shared connection to {RemoteServer} closed.

This is my ssh config file:

```
➜  ~ cat .ssh/config
Host n
HostName {RemoteServer}
User {UserName}
GSSAPIAuthentication no
ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist 10h
```

and I connect to my remote server with `ssh n` command.

I want to keep the connections. How can I achieve this?

Any comment or link appreciated!

Comment: `ControlPersist 10h` tells ssh that you only want the session to stay open while idle for a maximum of 10 hours.    Is that what you want?  If not, set it to `ControlPersist yes`.

Comment: Personally, I've found ssh's `Control*` options to be far more trouble than they're worth.  I recommend using `tmux` or `screen` to multiplex multiple terminal connections over a single ssh connection.   Also keeps the remote shells alive if you have to disconnect (you can reattach with tmux or screen next time you log in - which is useful for lots of reasons, including: if you need to hibernate the macbook, or if it has a dynamic IP address and you need to re-connect occasionally)